# Why won't my account link to Steam in Town of Salem?

Tags: steam, town-of-salem

I recently bought Town of Salem and you need to link an account in the game. I tried to link it to my steam account, but every time I try it says:

> error no user found

I'm sure that I wrote my username and password right and it still doesn`t work. It goes like this: open the game, sign in trough steam, choose link existing account, asks username and password, make sure that I write it right, click the login button, looking accounts for a few seconds and then comes a message that says error no user found.

How can I link my account?

Comment: Are you sure that's what they meant by 'link an account' ?

Comment: Also, try quoting the actual error in your post, this might make more sense to someone who has played the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account you need to link is your Town of Salem account for BlankMediaGames' forums , so make sure you've [registered on their website](http://www.blankmediagames.com/phpbb/ucp.php?mode=register) first.

Linking your Town of Salem website account to your Steam-bought copy of Town of Salem can sometimes fail mysteriously. [Shutting down Steam and restarting it](https://steamcommunity.com/app/334230/discussions/0/619574421202434293/) has helped for other people experiencing this bug.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a client error, this happened to me. Re-install Steam on your computer, it should work.

Comment: Well i know that it might be the right thing but i really don`t wanna wait again those annoying hours for my games to install. I`m gonna do it if its the last thing that i can do.